# Bug in my JavaScript code: Issue with synchronicity?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Reproduction Steps:

- Open http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html
- On the Video Playlist, enter `sMqNFAU0tOw` (or any Youtube video ID)
- Click *Play Videos!*
- JavaScript console should say something like `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

It is coming from this section of code, where I'm trying to use Google's JavaScript Youtube API to play Youtube videos consecutively:

```
                    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
                    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
                    swfobject.embedSWF(thisurl, "playerdiv", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
                    var ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
                    ytplayer.playVideo(); // <----- problem line
                   }
```

(API reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

I think that maybe it's because, when `playVideo` is called, the element `myytplayer` is still being created via the function `swfobject.embedSWF` ???? Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the problem. If try to debug your script and go step by step, you will see, that the code is working. But without that, you are trying to get the object which is still being created. 

`embedSWF` takes one more optional parameter - `callbackFn` *that is called on both success or failure of creating a Flash plug-in  on the page (SWFObject 2.2+)* (https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.embedSWF%28swfUrlStr,_replaceElemIdStr,_widthStr,_height). Try to put the code for getting the element and then playing the video inside such method.